# The Term '-Execution Policy' is not recognized

Tags: powershell

I would like to run such a statement in powershell:

```
-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File install-sshd.ps1
```

But I get this error message:

> -ExecutionPolicy : The term '-ExecutionPolicy' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

What should I do do to solve this issue?
Many thanks

Comment: `Set-ExecutionPolicy` https://ss64.com/ps/set-executionpolicy.html

Comment: While going through [playwright - getting started](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/intro) is was running into a similar issue. I solved it using `pwsh -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File  bin\Debug\net6.0\playwright.ps1 install`. If `pwsh` is not recognised you can install a new version `dotnet tool install --global PowerShell`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As for..
.
"Sorry, I am really new in PowerShel world. What is typo? – Kaja"

Please watch this series
 https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=beginning+powershell

If you are in the cmd prompt or any other cmd terminal, you do this..

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass "D:\Scripts\Script.ps1"
```

If you are already in the PowerShell console, or the PowerShell-ise.exe, you do this

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process
D:\Scripts\Script.ps1
```

It is technically not possible for you to get this error...
"The term '-ExecutionPolicy' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."
...unless you are not typing this correctly 
'-ExecutionPolicy' is only usable as a parameter after the powershell.exe or powershell_ise.exe executable.

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
(Get-Command -Name Get-ExecutionPolicy).Parameters
Get-help -Name Get-ExecutionPolicy -Examples
Get-help -Name Get-ExecutionPolicy -Full
Get-help -Name Get-ExecutionPolicy -Online

(Get-Command -Name Set-ExecutionPolicy).Parameters
Get-help -Name Set-ExecutionPolicy -Examples
Get-help -Name Set-ExecutionPolicy -Full
Get-help -Name Set-ExecutionPolicy -Online
```

Please try and copy one of the examples to attempt a run.

If you are doing this in an enterprise environment, and they have by policy disabled PowerShell on you machine or blocked this cmdlet use, then you'll not be able to use it.

Answer (score 21):

You need to put "PowerShell" in front of that:

```
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File install-sshd.ps1
```

`-ExecutionPolicy` is a parameter of the PowerShell .exe.

Comment: No, exact the same

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo?

Comment: Sorry, I am really new in PowerShel world. What is typo?

Comment: A typographical error, e.g you have incorrectly typed the command. Try copy/pasting the above.

Comment: This is the only thing that has worked for me, to add "Powershell"

Answer (score 1):

```
    powershell set-executionpolicy remotesigned
```

hi everyone, use this command to set the execution policy

Answer (score 1):

**What are Execaution Policies:**

Execution policies are just like a condition. A condition needs to be met to execute certain configurations or scripts. If not, the configuration or script will not run as expected.

**Keep In Mind that:**

They are not a security measure. In Microsoft words, execution policies are just basic rules. These rules prevent you from unintentionally violating the policies.

**How To Resolve:**

- Open Powershell and run *"Get-ExecutionPolicy"*. If it returns *Restricted* then run *"Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned"* or try *Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process.*

**Screenshot:**

[image: Execaution Policy]

Hope it Fix your problem.

Answer (score -1):

My Fix was turning off firewall protection, on my Antivirus program, then running PS commands and it worked.